# Show that the function satisfies $x^{2}f''(x)+xf'(x)+x^{2}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, summation

If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}$, show that $x^{2}f''(x)+xf'(x)+x^{2}f(x)=0$ $\forall x$.

I developed the function's first and second derivatives:

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{4^{n+1}((n+1)!)^{2}}$$

$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+2)(n+1)(-1)^{n+2}x^{2n}}{4^{n+2}((n+2)!)^{2}}$$

And then when I plug them in the differential equation, I don't get 0, no matter how much I try to simplify it. Should I look at the partial sums? Proof by induction? Any help would be appreciated! It's for an analysis course.

Comment: I am not sure if it will help you but you could try to convert the sum into an integral with the Euler-Mc-Laurin formula. I think it's easier to work with integrals than sums, especially in differential equations. [Leibniz-Rule will help you].

Comment: How does each derivative have the same power of $x$ with no sign of reindexing? Something tells me your method of differentiation is suspect.

Comment: The derivatives of f are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}$$
The derivative of $f(x)$ is not correct. You should have:
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(2n)x^{2n-1}}{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}$$
$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(2n(2n-1))x^{2n-2}}{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}$$
And:
$$xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(2n)x^{2n}}{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}$$
$$x^2f''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(2n(2n-1))x^{2n}}{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}$$
So that;
$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(4n^2)x^{2n}}{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}$$
Start the indice of the sum at $0$:
$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}x^{2m+2}}{4^{m}(m!)^{2}}$$
$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)=-x^2f(x)$$
Since you have this property:
$$(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$$

Comment: Ahh! Damn derivatives. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome @SpaceR